# Google Authenticator infinite loop on bugs.mojang.com

Tags: two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Yesterday I added a comment to a page on https://bugs.mojang.com which required me first to set up 2FA, which was easy because they provided a QR code which I used to add an entry in Google Authenticator on my Android phone (Galaxy S9+). I had done this once before for a different website, so there weren't any surprises and I was able to use 2FA and add the comment successfully.

Today, merely loading the same mojang webpage or the main page asked for a 2FA code again, as expected, so I opened Google Authenticator on my phone and it conveniently showed a 6-digit code and a countdown timer in the shape of a pie. Back on the website, I entered those 6 digits in the text entry box and click the Log In button. I expected the log in would finish and the page would load. Instead, the page merely seemed to refresh. No error message appeared.

Yesterday, I had marked the "Remember me" checkbox, which was supposed to keep me logged in for 720 hours, so actually, I shouldn't have encountered the 2FA interface for a month.

What I tried so far is...

- Tried several times in case of typos.
- Confirmed I was well within the pie's time limit which seems to be about 30 seconds.
- Tried with and without the space displayed in Google Authenticator.
- Tried using ecosia and superuser search for solutions.
- Tried entering a 2-factor reserve key (after clicking that link on the 2FA log-in page) but it simply returned me to the 2FA page without any comment or error.
- Tried on a different day.

Encountered while trying to solve this issue...

[How to overcome "jni error has occurred" after Minecraft and Java update in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1696054/how-to-overcome-jni-error-has-occurred-after-minecraft-and-java-update-in-wind)

I can't tell you the exact URL of the https://bugs.mojang.com page where the comment was successful because I can't access the site in any way without 2FA, but it was just an unremarkable Jira-style bug ticket's main page.

The situation is so simple that I can't figure out what I could possibly be doing wrong, but it's only the second time I've used Google Authenticator for 2FA. (I often used Okta's authenticator app on an iPhone for work a couple of years ago, and it seems to work exactly the same way.)

Comment: Small chance, but this happens for me when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: @Aganju, I confirmed with MS Edge that enabling/disabling JavaScript doesn't solve. I don't see any JavaScript setting in Firefox, but confirmed with that that it doesn't appear to be browser-specific either.